# Script (tie-able to a keystroke) that slows down the mouse for fine movements? Or app that does this?

Tags: mouse

Sometimes when doing graphics work one needs to briefly slow down the mouse movement to make fine pixel-by-pixel movements. One can chance this setting in **System Preferences: Mouse**, but it then becomes too slow for regular size movements amount the screen. Does AppleScript or any other program allow you to switch this mouse speed quicker than using System Preferences? (Ideally this'd be in a way that could be tied to a keystroke through some method.)

Answer (score 2):

Get a gaming mouse that allows you to adjust sensitivity on the fly

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: I appreciate the option; others may find it helpful, but I'll see if the question gets a direct answer.